# Can't find headers for GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK with Cocoapods 0.37, Swift, frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

Using cocoa pods 0.37.0 in a Swift project, with use_frameworks! set in the podfile, I am unable to access the header files for the GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK pod.

How should I access the Google Analytics pod's headers in my app?

I have tried;

```
import GoogleAnalytics_iOS_SDK
```

In a Swift file, cocoapods 0.36 style. But there's no framework created anymore so no good.

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics_iOS_SDK/GAI.h>
```

In the bridging header, but doesn't work (no module map ?)

---

I have read that the behaviour for pods that only include headers in their 'sourse_files' changed in cocoapods 0.37 [(see this commit)](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3468). This appears to be in response to the problems that use_frameworks caused with these pods in 0.36 [(see this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792243/googleanalytics-ios-sdk-on-cocoapods-0-36-with-swift).

With this change in Cocoapod behaviour, the static library is integrated correctly (it wasn't with 0.36), the symbols are compiled into the app and available at runtime. But I don't have access to the headers.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am getting error at #import <Google/Analytics.h> --> file not found

Comment: @techsavvy please read the accepted answer, it explains a workaround.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a bug in Cocoapods 0.37.0. It has been logged in their tracker as [issue #3499](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3499).

**Workaround**

- Add `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK` to the `User Header Search Paths` (set to Recursive) in the app target's `Build Settings`.
- Reference the Google Analytics header directly in the Bridging Header with `#import "GAI.h"`

Comment: I'm very unhappy about having to add a bridging header just for this, but seems like this is the only valid option currently.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: This issue might still be in CocoaPods 0.39.0, which I'm using at the moment. I added the User Header Search Paths and it works, but I can't seem to get the GGLContext to work for errors.

Anyway, thanks a bunch, saved me a lot of hair since I was about to rip it all off in frustration.

Comment: What a mess. Answers by Fabric seems the better option now.

Comment: The Google analytics pod also causes lldb to break. After removing it, objects can be inpected and debugged as usual.

Comment: Worked for me, especially `#import "GAI.h"` part.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick is to add long relative path(s) to the bridging header.

This avoids having to make changes to project settings which may be overridden next time you run `pod install':

```
#import "../../Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Headers/Public/GAI.h"
#import "../../Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Headers/Public/GAIFields.h"
#import "../../Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Headers/Public/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

It also works when running your unit tests too, which another solution I tried didn't.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the correct answer or not, but the way we got it to work was to manually import `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and not via cocoapods.

Locate `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and drag it into the project, then add it to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` (if it's not there already) and you're good to go. Don't forget to remove it from your `Podfile`.

edit:
Don't forget to add the header files to your bridging-header

Comment: Thanks, this is my contingency plan. I would like to get it working with Cocoapods, so I will leave the question open for a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on CocoaPods 0.39.0.

$(inherited) in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' solved it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32004207/3129306