# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: after integrating cocoa pods for Google App Invytes iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, social-networking, google-app-invites

```
Ld /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zingcy.app/Zingcy normal i386
    cd "/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy 24 Cocoajuly 2015"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleParsingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GooglePlusUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Zingcy/Utilities/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries -L& -LHeaders -F/Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/AppInvites/Frameworks -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GPPCore/Frameworks -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Pods/GoogleMobileAds/Frameworks -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Zingcy -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015/Zingcy/Utilities -F/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy\ 24\ Cocoajuly\ 2015 -filelist /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Intermediates/Zingcy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zingcy.build/Objects-normal/i386/Zingcy.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CoreData -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework Security -framework TwitterKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreText -framework CoreMotion -framework FacebookSDK -framework CoreGraphics -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AddressBook -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework GooglePlus -framework SystemConfiguration -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Intermediates/Zingcy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zingcy.build/Objects-normal/i386/Zingcy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Zingcy.app/Zingcy

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pallavi/Downloads/Zingcy 24 Cocoajuly 2015/Zingcy/Utilities/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L&'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LHeaders'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/pallavi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zingcy-flapxefzelxuhkdzrfjzikpzkylo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a

**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FindPeopleViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GINInvite", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FindPeopleViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

I have done all the configuration for Google App InVytes but as soon as i compile n try to run my project i face these errors Please suggest Thanks In advance

Comment: add $(inherited) in other linker flag.
Refreanced by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108868/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-objc-class-gglcontext-referenced

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:-

- Included the SafariServices framework (Goto target->Build phases->Link binrary with libraries)
- The linker flag -ObjC (not -Objc) (Goto target->Build settings->Other linker flags)
- Disabled BIT_CODE (Goto target->Build settings->Enable bitcode)

Answer (score 0):

Going to app Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> other linker flag then add $(inherited) hope this will work for you.