# use_frameworks! in cocoapods for analytics

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to use google analytics in my swift app. I have to install it via cocoapods. I was already using cocoapods for haneke library. But haneke library says "you have to put `use_frameworks!` line. But If I put this line I can't install google analytics via cocoapods. How can I resolve this? My pod file:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Error:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing Google (1.0.7)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.12.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.0.1)
Using HanekeSwift (0.9.1)
[!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_core.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries/libGSDK_Overload.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_iPhone.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_core.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_UIFont+LineHeight.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_SystemVersion.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_StringEncoding.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_RoundedRectPath.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_Regex.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringXML.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringHTML.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSScannerJSON.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_KVO.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_GTMURLBuilder.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_DebugUtils.a, /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_AddressBook.a, and /Users/tolgaytoklar/Documents/Ribony/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTMStackTrace.a)
```

How can I resolve this?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target for 8.0 and use CocoaPods 0.37 or later.

For earlier version, the answer is here:
[GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK on CocoaPods 0.36 with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792243/googleanalytics-ios-sdk-on-cocoapods-0-36-with-swift)