# Google Analytics v3 Pod with other Swift Pods

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods, google-analytics-sdk

I'm developing an swift iOS app and at this "final" stage I'll add Google Analytics.

I'm following their [Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift)

But it failed at `pod install` command...

Error Log

`Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (1.2.2)
Using Bolts (1.2.0)
Using CryptoSwift (0.0.10)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.2.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.2.0)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.2.0)
Installing Google (1.0.7)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.13.0)
Using GoogleMaps (1.10.1)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.0.1)
Using ImageLoader (0.3.2)
Using SQLite.swift (0.1.0.pre)
Using SwiftyJSON (2.2.0)
[!] The 'Pods-<My-Project>' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (<path-to-project-dir>/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLAnalytics.a, <path-to-project-dir>/iOS/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a, <path-to-project-dir>/iOS/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a, (...)`

As stated in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift), "pods written in Swift must be created as dynamic frameworks" (and that's why the `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile).
As it seems, this new Google Analytics pod is a static binary.

I tried to change the pod the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907523/2789106) but the `pod install` command warned me that (obviously) `[!] GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK has been deprecated in favor of GoogleAnalytics`. And I'm not sure it's a good idea to add an already deprecated library to a new project instead of getting the right one to work.

My project has a target dependecy to iOS 8.0+ and the podfile is:
``` 
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'ImageLoader', '~> 0.3.0'
  pod 'SQLite.swift', git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.13'
end

target 'MyProjectTests' do

end 
```

Is anyone having the same problem or know how to solve this using the v3 GA pod?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10'
```

in your Podfile with

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.13'
```

Clean project and run pod install again. The pod you're currently using is the one that is deprecated.

Comment: if you check de LogError the pod I tried to install was the one you listed (the not deprecated one). But you are right, I've written the wrong Podile here (I copied the one I was testing with the deprecated library). Editing the post, tks!